# Php array: How can I echo the value of this?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to echo a setting on the second level of an array in my wordpress options and having some trouble getting the variable.  This code DOES work:

```
 <?php foreach($area['fields'] as $field): ?>
 <?php if ($field['id'] == 'show_border')
  {echo ' show_border';} ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That simply checks if there is a field that asks if you want to show a border and if there is it echos whatever I want, regardless of what the field is set at for actually showing the border or not.

What I am trying to do is to just echo the value that is set in the field "show_border".

Any idea how I would do this?

**edit**

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "# of posts"
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "posts"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "posts per row"
    ["id"]=>
    string(13) "posts_per_row"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "select"
    ["default"]=>
    int(3)
    ["options"]=>
    array(8) {
      [1]=>
      int(1)
      [2]=>
      int(2)
      [3]=>
      int(3)
      [4]=>
      int(4)
      [5]=>
      int(5)
      [6]=>
      int(6)
      [7]=>
      int(7)
      [8]=>
      int(8)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "header type"
    ["id"]=>
    string(13) "f_header_type"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "select"
    ["default"]=>
    string(2) "h4"
    ["options"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["h1"]=>
      string(2) "h1"
      ["h2"]=>
      string(2) "h2"
      ["h3"]=>
      string(2) "h3"
      ["h4"]=>
      string(2) "h4"
      ["h5"]=>
      string(2) "h5"
      ["h6"]=>
      string(2) "h6"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "icon?"
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "show_icon"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "radio"
    ["default"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["options"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["yes"]=>
      string(3) "yes"
      ["no"]=>
      string(2) "no"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "icon location"
    ["id"]=>
    string(13) "icon_location"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "select"
    ["default"]=>
    string(4) "left"
    ["options"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["left"]=>
      string(4) "left"
      ["right"]=>
      string(5) "right"
      ["top"]=>
      string(3) "top"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "show text?"
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "show_text"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "radio"
    ["default"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["options"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["yes"]=>
      string(3) "yes"
      ["no"]=>
      string(2) "no"
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "show border?"
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "show_border"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "radio"
    ["default"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["options"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["top"]=>
      string(3) "top"
      ["bot"]=>
      string(3) "bot"
      ["no"]=>
      string(2) "no"
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "select"
    ["multiple"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["options"]=>
    array(2) {
      [4]=>
      string(7) "feature"
      [3]=>
      string(6) "slider"
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "custom classes"
    ["id"]=>
    string(14) "custom_classes"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["default"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [9]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "read more?"
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "read_more"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "radio"
    ["default"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["options"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["yes"]=>
      string(3) "yes"
      ["no"]=>
      string(2) "no"
    }
  }
  [10]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "read more text"
    ["id"]=>
    string(14) "read_more_text"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["default"]=>
    string(16) "Continue reading"
  }
}
```

I am trying to get a value like ["id"]=> "show_border" and echo it's value.

Comment: what does your array look like?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: "Not working" is not very helpful.

Comment: Using the methods that should give me the value such as "top" I am instead getting something weird like "p p f s i s s c c r r"

Comment: Please add a dump the the array $field, we cannot guess its content.

Comment: what are you trying to do again?

Comment: "This code DOES work:..." problem solved?

Comment: Problem would be what is described in the next sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't get the form value in PHP which you're going to select from the form which was already loaded on the server-side.

It's like going from the future to the past.

You should use Javascript code + AJAX, instead of PHP, but it'll be much more complex.
Without knowing the full source of the site, it's not possible to tell you in one simple answer.

Also it depends on your development skills.

Comment: Yeah i added a var_dump to the op

Comment: I'm not really sure.  I didn't write the original code.  That code you wrote outputs the default value but not the current one.  I don't think it is using ajax to pass the value because it doesn't change until I update the post in wordpress.

Comment: if your value is not in that array, can you var_dump($_POST); when you submitting the form?

Comment: Hmm it is using ajax to save what is entered.

Comment: Is the foreach code which you're trying to execute, is when the form is shown, when posted, or during AJAX request?

Comment: So at that time when the form is shown, PHP doesn't know which values you are going to select. Once the form is shown, PHP code execution is finished. So how you want to achieve that? You should write the code in Javascript (with AJAX) rather than in PHP, if you want to display this value on that form which is already loaded.

Comment: How does it know which value to show as selected when the page loads?

Comment: You should check in Firebug what exactly is sent to the server and if anything is dynamic on the page (once the form was loaded), it's not PHP, but Javascript getting this information via AJAX from the server.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  I will make a new question about how to do this with javascript.  Thanks for helping me.